# JS Overlay Menu Not Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to display [this](https://codepen.io/RSH87/pen/rmgYbo) full screen overlay menu (which works great) on my web page, on the top left hand side. My code so far can be seen [here](https://codepen.io/johnny_s/pen/bvbGYB).

When I click the overlay menu, it seems to be 'hidden' behind the main page content.

I changed some of the `z-index` values for the overlay menu, but when I did this the main page navigation (element called `slick-dots`) stopped working (visible but not clickable).

When the overlay menu is open, the navigation (`slick-dots`) should be hidden. However when the full screen menu is closed, the navigation should be visible and work.

I'm not sure how I should configure the `z-index` or `position` values in order to achieve what I want?

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: .menu-icon{z-index: 9999} .nav{z-index: 999} works for example.

Comment: Thanks @Steve but that doesn't work. When I make the changes you have suggested the menu stays open constantly, that's not what I want. Any other suggestions?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LdPGKx with the index changes

Comment: @Steve your pen is only showing the overlay menu.

Answer (score 1):

With the z-index solution you mentioned, you couldn't click your slick-dots nav because when you use `visibility: hidden` instead of `display: none`, the element is still there, taking up space on top of everything else, intercepting mouse events. You can use `pointer-events: none` along with `visibility` to let hovers and clicks fall through it.

```
.nav {
  visibility: hidden;
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 100;
}

body.nav-active .nav {
  visibility: visible;
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

[Here's a Pen of it working.](https://codepen.io/75th/pen/Wzewjq) `pointer-events` only works in IE11, so if you need to support IE10 you'll have to add some sort of workaround.